# Python's tkinter smart entry password

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, passwords

I want to create a password entry.

One easy solution is:

```
password = Entry(root, font="Verdana 22")
password.config(show="*");
```

but the problem is that to avoid typos, I want to show the item clicked to be visible only for a few seconds, while everything else is hidden. After a few seconds everything is hidden.

Comment: What part of the problem do you need help with? Or are you asking us to write the whole code for you?

Comment: I have already hidden all entries by default, but the part i am having trouble with is showing only the last item added to the entry hidden for a few seconds

Comment: I don't think it is available out-of-the-box in tkinter. You can implement it, using `root.after` and remembering user's input. Or add a checkbox that display/hide password.

Comment: thanks. could you elaborate a bit on .after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not easy to do exactly what you want with Tkinter, but here's something close: when you press a key it displays the whole contents of the Entry, but after one second the text is hidden again.

I developed this on Python 2; to use it on Python 3 change `Tkinter` to `tkinter`.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class PasswordTest(object):
    ''' Password Entry Demo '''
    def __init__(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title("Password Entry Demo")

        self.entry = e = tk.Entry(root)
        e.pack()
        e.bind("<Key>", self.entry_cb)

        b = tk.Button(root, text="show", command=self.button_cb)
        b.pack()

        root.mainloop()

    def entry_cb(self, event):
        #print(`event.char`, event.keycode, event.keysym )
        self.entry.config(show='')
        #Hide text after 1000 milliseconds
        self.entry.after(1000, lambda: self.entry.config(show='*'))

    def button_cb(self):
        print('Contents:', repr(self.entry.get()))

PasswordTest()
```

It would be tricky to *only* display the last char entered. You'd have to modify the displayed string manually while maintaining the real password string in a separate variable and that's a bit fiddly because the user can move the insertion point cursor at any time.

On a final note, I *really* don't recommend doing *anything* like this. Keep passwords hidden at *all* times! If you want to reduce the chance of typos in newly-chosen passwords, the usual practice is to make the user enter the password twice.

Answer (score 0):

This a simple trick to visible the password with a checkbutton.
When it is checked the password will be visible

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def show_hide_psw():
    if check_var.get():
        entry_psw.config(show="")
        return
    entry_psw.config(show="*")


window = tk.Tk()
window.wm_title("Password")

window.geometry("300x100+30+30")
window.resizable(0, 0)

entry_psw = ttk.Entry(window, width=30, show="*")
entry_psw.place(x=5, y=25)

check_var = tk.IntVar()
check_show_psw = ttk.Checkbutton(
    window,
    text="Show",
    variable=check_var,
    onvalue=1,
    offvalue=0,
    command=show_hide_psw,
    )
check_show_psw.place(x=5, y=50)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is nice, but not what the OP asked for.